# Why does my loop terminate even with a condition?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, break

I am trying to get user input and store them in an array Fib[i]. After that print the Fib[i] array. When the user enters -1 the loop will quit and the program will end. But my code is not printing or terminating.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Fib[50];//globally declared  
int fib(int n)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<50; i++)
    {   
        scanf("%d", &Fib[i]); 
        if(i==-1)
         break;
       //printf("numbers entered %d\n", Fib[i]); // <- doesn't terminate if printf is here
    }
        printf("numbers entered %d\n", Fib[i]); //doesn't print anything??

}
int main()
{
    int i, n;
//calling the function
    fib(n);

return 0;

}
```

user input:

```
4
5
-1
```

Expected output:

```
Numbers entered 
4
5
```

Comment: i won't be -1. i is your loop variable. Fib[i] might be -1

Comment: How will `i` ever be negative in that loop?

Comment: Also `Fib` is an array of doubles and you're telling `scanf()` to assign an int to an element of it. Isn't your compiler warning you about that?

Comment: @Shawn The user input will be -1 which will then terminate the loop because i can't be -1.

Comment: No the compiler didn't say anything.

Comment: You never compare your user input against anything, and if you fix that, it's still not going to work until you fix your use of `scanf()`.

Comment: **Always** turn on a healthy set of warnings, and pay attention to them. `-Wall -Wextra` is good if using gcc or clang.

Answer (score 4):

First issue: you declare `Fib` as an array of `double`:

```
double Fib[50];
```

But you use `%d` to read the values, which is for reading an `int`:

```
scanf("%d", &Fib[i]);
```

Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You presumably want to store integers, so change the array to `int`:

```
int Fib[50];
```

Next is your array breakout condition:

```
if(i==-1)
```

`i` is your array index, which ranges from 0 to 49, so this will never be true.  You want to stop when the user enters -1, and that value will be in `Fib[i]`:

```
if(Fib[i]==-1)
```

Finally, printing the array:

```
printf("numbers entered %d\n", Fib[i]);
```

This doesn't print the array.  It just prints the element at the last index of `i`, and the value at that index will always be -1.  You need a separate loop to print the values:

```
int j;
printf("numbers entered:\n");
for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
    printf("%d\n", Fib[j]);
}
```

Comment: So I fixed it but now it goes to infinite loop of 0.                                                                for(i=0; i<50 && i>=0; i++)
  {   
   scanf("%lf", &Fib[i]); 
   if(Fib[i]==-1) //changed
    break;   
  } 
  
  printf("numbers entered " );
  
  for(j=0; j<sizeof(Fib); i++) //why is j<i ??? i is seprate right? what is i here?
  {  
  printf("%d\n", Fib[j]);
    }

Comment: @Su.she You changed the `scanf` format specifier to `%lf` but left the `printf` one as `%d`.  Either use `double` for all or use `int` for all.  Using `sizeof(Fib)` is not correct because that is the number of *bytes* in `Fib`, not the number of elements.  We're using `i` instead because that was the index of the last value the user entered, so once `j` hits `i` we can stop.

Answer (score 1):

This code has many code writing standard issues but it seems you are new so I am making minimal changes just for your understanding

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Fib[50];//globally declared  
int fib(int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<50; i++)
    {   
        scanf("%lf", &Fib[i]); 
        if(Fib[i]==-1)
         break;
    }  
    printf("numbers entered \n");
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",Fib[j]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i, n;
    fib(n);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I made the changes after seeing your code.                                                                                            
              for(i=0; i<50 && i>=0; i++)
  {   
   scanf("%d", &Fib[i]); 
   if(Fib[i]==-1) //changed
    break;
  }
 
  printf("numbers entered ");
    
  //new loop
  for(j=0; j<sizeof(Fib); j++)
   printf("%lf\n", Fib[i]);                                                                                     but it stil didn't work.

Comment: I wrote this in hurry , some heartless have downvoted me @Su.she . I have edited but I think if(Fib[i]==-1) is the problem now

Comment: @chux  I changed the lf part but now this is only printing -1.00000 after the loop ends.     for(i=0; i<50 && i>=0; i++)
  {   
   scanf("%lf", &Fib[i]); 
   if(Fib[i]==-1) //changed
    break;   
  }    
  printf("numbers entered %lf\n", Fib[i]);

Comment: @Su.she just confirm the code is working or not https://ideone.com/xGvPad

Comment: @Su.she sometimes what happen is 1 in double is taken as 1.000000001 and so 1 != 1.000000001 so u might get a error